# How to manage Laravel queues on deployments?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have an HA architecture for Laravel with multiple web and queue servers and zero downtime deployments. It relies on Redis as queue driver.

The issue is that when deploying a new version of the code, there is no way to prevent the new queue workers from processing jobs coming from old code versions, when performing a rolling update of the cluster.

Is there a way in Laravel to filter jobs coming from a different code version than the queue worker?

Comment: are you using supervisors for queues

Comment: The queue workers are actually in docker containers, I create and deploy new containers for every new version. But I could use supervisor if it's a solution.

Comment: Hey @IgnacioMillán where you able to solve this. Im encountering the same problem but I cant find any example of a solution or best practices for this. I have a couple ideas but I want to see if there is a already proven way of solving this

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions, even if i never tried and i cannot guarantee it works as i will not describe all technical issues you may encounter.

In both cases you need a code version stored somewhere in env / config with update at each release.

### First solution

For all jobs that are concerned by that issue the version value needs to be part of the parameters that are dispatched with the job itself.

At the start of job handle function compare that version from job param = version from worker env. If not the job needs to redispatch itself... it might end up being handled by the right "version" of worker or you can discard it plain and simple.

### Second solution

Dynamically include version code inside the queue names. That way each time you release yo will have new workers listening to new queue names. That way you have a real version isolation regarding jobs & workers.